# How to get RANDOM records from each category in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database, I have a table with different questions in different categories.

I would like to write a SQL statement that returns 3 RANDOM questions of EACH category.

**Here is an example of database records:**

```
id  question    category
1   Question A  1
2   Question B  1
3   Question C  1
4   Question D  1
5   Question D  1
6   Question F  2
7   Question G  2
8   Question H  2
9   Question I  2
10  Question J  2
11  Question K  3
12  Question L  3
13  Question M  3
14  Question N  3
15  Question O  3
16  Question P  3
```

**Here is output/results of 3 Random selected and shuffled from all questions of each category from the above list:**

```
2   Question B  1
4   Question D  1
3   Question C  1
10  Question J  2
7   Question G  2
9   Question I  2
11  Question K  3
15  Question P  3
13  Question M  3
```

I have so far played with the following statement for testing:

```
SELECT * FROM `random` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3;
```

This return only 3 RANDOM questions from all categories.

And I have afterwards looked for example at this link:
[MYSQL select random of each of the categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626622/mysql-select-random-of-each-of-the-categories)

And tried this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `random` WHERE category = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `random` WHERE category = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `random` WHERE category = 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
```

But here I need to add each category manually.

**My Question:** I was a wonder if it is at all possible to fetch 3 RANDOM records/rows from each category of all categories (automatically)?

---

**EDIT**

This is not part of the question but help.

**Dummy data creator**
The query code will table called `random` and created a stored procedure called `create_random` and when you run the stored procedure, it will create random dummy data inside a random table:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `random`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_random` $$

CREATE TABLE `random` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `question` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `category` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=401
;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `create_random`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''

BEGIN

DECLARE v_max int unsigned DEFAULT 100;
DECLARE v_counter int unsigned DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cat_counter int unsigned DEFAULT 0;

  TRUNCATE TABLE `random`;
  START TRANSACTION;
  WHILE v_counter < v_max DO
    IF v_counter %10=0 THEN SET cat_counter=cat_counter+1;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO `random` (question, category) VALUES ( CONCAT('Question', FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 65535))), cat_counter );
    SET v_counter=v_counter+1;
  END WHILE;
  COMMIT;
END
```

**Note:** I tried all answers and all works fine. Gordon Linoff and pjanaway answer select RANDOM only from top 3 or bottom 3 questions, I have checked Gordon answer because he answered first, but that does not mean other answers is not good, all of them are good and it is up to users to pick the right answer or combination of answers. I love all the answers and vote them up. Drew Pierce answer newly to this question, it is more interesting right now and almost near the goal. Thanks to all.

Comment: Really cool would be if the words in the questions were random too. But seriously it looks like you are 90% there. Is it that you want the presentation order to be shuffled a bit (that is, not one category followed by the other) ? Or is it the last part I finally read three times: that you want it all automatic not manual adding of a new union for each new category ? Probably the latter, sorry.

Comment: @DrewPierce, yes, the idea sql statement should shuffled the questions of the same category so people answer or getting the question should not expect to get same questions all time. The example is small, but there will be a lot of questions of each and different category, just imagine if I added new category each week, then I need to modify my sql statement constantly, but if I do it some way automatically then it will make my day easier ;) lol

Comment: this question hopefully earns you some well deserved points as it seems to be highly useful in many settings !

Comment: That make me happy if some one get benefit of it, as I started with it, it sounded very easy task to achieve but faster turned to complicated question to solve (for me perhaps) and I am glad and thankful for people in this community welling to help and contribute, on count of there time. respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by enumerating the rows and then fetching the top three:

```
select r.id, r.question, r.category
from (select r.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = category, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := category, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from `random` r cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := -1) params
      order by category, rand()
     ) r
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: greetings Gordon. I am having problems with the results. probably best to read the pastie under pj's answer below **first**, then this one with your inner query. http://pastie.org/10300277

Comment: There is a little challenge here. Now I have build a bigger random database for testing, and when I run your code and pjanaway both of them select three question and keep shuffling them but when I run the code again it keeps the same questions, the idea was I have more then three questions in each category, it should take 3 of them and random pick from all questions and shuffle them. In your code it keeps takes only the first three questions and @pjanaway it take the last three questions?

Comment: @maytham . . . If the code is returning the same three questions, then one possibility is that the seed to the random number generator is being reset.  You can try to set it manually to see if you get different results (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answer, this is also another way to do it.

```
SELECT r.* FROM random r
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM random r1
  WHERE r.category = r1.category AND r.id < r1.id
) <= 2
ORDER BY r.category ASC, RAND()
```

Comment: I can't get Gordon's to work but I can get this to work. will show a pastie

Comment: @DrewPierce This code works more compact, we have updated Gordon answer have you tried the last update?

Comment: yes i tried it 3 times i know it was updated but i will try again

Comment: ok, so the results from pjanaway came back as expected, 17 categories, 3 each, 51 rows

Comment: Gordon's comes back with all 300 rows (even after several edit tests) because of a problem with the inner query 4th column `seqnum` that is 90%=1 and 10%=2  (ish)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83641/discussion-between-maytham-and-drew-pierce).

Answer (score 1):

```
create schema so_gibberish; -- creates database 
use so_gibberish;   -- use it 

-- drop table random;   -- during debug
create table random 
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    question varchar(50) not null,
    category int not null,
    randomOrder int not null,
    key (category)
);

-- drop table questions_for_user;   -- during debug
create table questions_for_user 
(   physcOrder int auto_increment primary key,
    id int not null,
    question varchar(50) not null,
    category int not null,
    randomOrder int not null,
    key (category)
);
```

Create a stored procedure to insert random questions. It creates 300 at a time when you call it.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
drop procedure if exists createRandomQuestions$$ 
-- 17 categories of questions randomly created. yes random word questions and categories.

create procedure createRandomQuestions()
BEGIN
set @i=1;
WHILE @i<=300 DO
insert random (question,category) values ('xxx',1);
SELECT @lid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();  -- use id to seed, next 8 guaranteed different i think

UPDATE random SET question=concat(
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@lid)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed)*36+1, 1), ' ?'
), category=floor(rand()*17+1),randomOrder=0
WHERE id=@lid;
set @i=@i+1;
END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

call it:

```
call createRandomQuestions();
```

to check:

```
select category,count(*) from random group by category order by category;
select count(*) from random;
select * from random limit 10;
```

Now get three random questions for each category for a user upon request.

Come up with a good random SEEDING algorithm. The below is a stub, best to use an external source like http to a service, etc.

```
update random set randomOrder=rand()*unix_timestamp();
truncate table questions_for_user;
insert into questions_for_user (id,question,category,randomOrder)
select id,question,category,randomOrder from random order by rand();

select r.* 
FROM questions_for_user r 
WHERE 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM random r1 WHERE r.category = r1.category AND r.id < r1.id ) <= 2 
ORDER by r.category ASC, randomOrder;

+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
| physcOrder | id  | question   | category | randomOrder |
+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
|        297 | 266 | JNQH26DD ? |        1 |   841700408 |
|        247 | 286 | ORK15577 ? |        1 |   980764662 |
|         54 | 267 | T2HPRW88 ? |        1 |  1331420535 |
|        190 | 275 | U5BFCUFF ? |        2 |   836160445 |
|        192 | 285 | E3KDJ144 ? |        2 |  1166207975 |
|         55 | 293 | GFWQ0BEE ? |        2 |  1356597807 |
|        266 | 296 | 8MJCWR55 ? |        3 |  1121232849 |
|        173 | 288 | 6GGOI2CC ? |        3 |  1209081435 |
|        205 | 231 | LQMYMV44 ? |        3 |  1330946482 |
|        103 | 289 | FUODJHJJ ? |        4 |   392498036 |
|        274 | 295 | Y85VNBWW ? |        4 |   613800522 |
|        204 | 280 | 441X1YTT ? |        4 |  1141251557 |
|        162 | 273 | CC5FGKFF ? |        5 |    99041401 |
|         36 | 252 | Y7V58ZEE ? |        5 |  1124240820 |
|        143 | 234 | DWZULKBB ? |        5 |  1286225785 |
|         15 | 276 | 3J1KGJZZ ? |        6 |    51285374 |
|        265 | 294 | PTEMZ7GG ? |        6 |   649256602 |
|         91 | 271 | TNG23R11 ? |        6 |  1393790410 |
|         90 | 277 | DXE1W0GG ? |        7 |   622567356 |
|         20 | 274 | LQTFS7RR ? |        7 |  1376505632 |
|        121 | 279 | VQN6TVSS ? |        7 |  1428714367 |
|        268 | 265 | A99UU1YY ? |        8 |   479923553 |
|        242 | 284 | 5PDRR5YY ? |        8 |   658551160 |
|        283 | 282 | NWZSPCZZ ? |        8 |   802197234 |
|        114 | 233 | 3IHU1YKK ? |        9 |   118146688 |
|         85 | 226 | BQTD6A44 ? |        9 |   292147382 |
|        255 | 291 | YNT0YN11 ? |        9 |   559911752 |
|        281 | 258 | IHK46577 ? |       10 |   196799301 |
|        198 | 263 | SHEVXPBB ? |       10 |   545833955 |
|         11 | 298 | QEHHSAEE ? |       10 |  1087006220 |
|         60 | 250 | GEH9PVBB ? |       11 |   225193615 |
|        270 | 272 | 3YY2EMM ?  |       11 |  1143544695 |
|        300 | 290 | O8B4WRCC ? |       11 |  1209867696 |
|         68 | 246 | FTEEVJ00 ? |       12 |   608441021 |
|        177 | 244 | X1JYHUBB ? |       12 |  1192309224 |
|        208 | 240 | W771N588 ? |       12 |  1347800170 |
|        249 | 300 | 97V6UXYY ? |       13 |   500846709 |
|        100 | 292 | 71JZTMQQ ? |       13 |   607266604 |
|         38 | 283 | WBQ0DGLL ? |       13 |  1187952919 |
|         87 | 235 | MBPPXJ44 ? |       14 |   327445349 |
|        178 | 242 | EZ1ET3ZZ ? |       14 |   852480639 |
|         62 | 281 | EIHVH3ZZ ? |       14 |  1420114728 |
|         95 | 251 | PT8E2CII ? |       15 |    72502146 |
|        170 | 253 | 8L35PFYY ? |       15 |  1091765038 |
|         65 | 287 | X5ZR3LHH ? |       15 |  1405199431 |
|        138 | 278 | MBW03OUU ? |       16 |    84358922 |
|          7 | 268 | 2G4G42WW ? |       16 |  1257379717 |
|          1 | 299 | ZT8QRRMM ? |       16 |  1327297420 |
|        221 | 297 | H00HLNRR ? |       17 |   890140945 |
|         40 | 204 | O7VUW2NN ? |       17 |  1238474743 |
|        122 | 229 | 3XEZG0PP ? |       17 |  1359337651 |
+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
51 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Run it again for next user or same guy:

```
update random set randomOrder=rand()*unix_timestamp();
truncate table questions_for_user;
insert into questions_for_user (id,question,category,randomOrder)
select id,question,category,randomOrder from random order by rand();

select r.* 
FROM questions_for_user r 
WHERE 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM random r1 WHERE r.category = r1.category AND r.id < r1.id ) <= 2 
ORDER by r.category ASC, randomOrder;

+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
| physcOrder | id  | question   | category | randomOrder |
+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
|        112 | 286 | ORK15577 ? |        1 |   193281314 |
|        176 | 266 | JNQH26DD ? |        1 |   530153269 |
|        296 | 267 | T2HPRW88 ? |        1 |   891041924 |
|         37 | 293 | GFWQ0BEE ? |        2 |   222852606 |
|        239 | 285 | E3KDJ144 ? |        2 |   679635152 |
|        262 | 275 | U5BFCUFF ? |        2 |   846163956 |
|         95 | 288 | 6GGOI2CC ? |        3 |  1244253481 |
|         81 | 231 | LQMYMV44 ? |        3 |  1380298624 |
|         59 | 296 | 8MJCWR55 ? |        3 |  1420850554 |
|         28 | 295 | Y85VNBWW ? |        4 |   806083444 |
|         30 | 289 | FUODJHJJ ? |        4 |   814854070 |
|         34 | 280 | 441X1YTT ? |        4 |  1119188021 |
|        232 | 234 | DWZULKBB ? |        5 |   296692881 |
|        295 | 273 | CC5FGKFF ? |        5 |   337915901 |
|        140 | 252 | Y7V58ZEE ? |        5 |   644987638 |
|        257 | 271 | TNG23R11 ? |        6 |   619359840 |
|         27 | 294 | PTEMZ7GG ? |        6 |   869855570 |
|        218 | 276 | 3J1KGJZZ ? |        6 |  1390090875 |
|         64 | 279 | VQN6TVSS ? |        7 |    33942495 |
|        290 | 277 | DXE1W0GG ? |        7 |   100007602 |
|        173 | 274 | LQTFS7RR ? |        7 |   946909650 |
|        291 | 265 | A99UU1YY ? |        8 |   107468716 |
|         49 | 284 | 5PDRR5YY ? |        8 |  1068298164 |
|        228 | 282 | NWZSPCZZ ? |        8 |  1115906220 |
|        284 | 226 | BQTD6A44 ? |        9 |    45678738 |
|        179 | 291 | YNT0YN11 ? |        9 |   700305900 |
|        164 | 233 | 3IHU1YKK ? |        9 |  1416089612 |
|        193 | 258 | IHK46577 ? |       10 |   460111512 |
|        214 | 298 | QEHHSAEE ? |       10 |   482322673 |
|          7 | 263 | SHEVXPBB ? |       10 |   766681927 |
|        178 | 290 | O8B4WRCC ? |       11 |   341509950 |
|         31 | 272 | 3YY2EMM ?  |       11 |   726662739 |
|        297 | 250 | GEH9PVBB ? |       11 |  1386568968 |
|         32 | 240 | W771N588 ? |       12 |   303493686 |
|        283 | 246 | FTEEVJ00 ? |       12 |   710591266 |
|        177 | 244 | X1JYHUBB ? |       12 |   916685336 |
|        212 | 283 | WBQ0DGLL ? |       13 |   595739692 |
|        159 | 300 | 97V6UXYY ? |       13 |   688431139 |
|         52 | 292 | 71JZTMQQ ? |       13 |  1039681379 |
|         56 | 235 | MBPPXJ44 ? |       14 |   109832248 |
|        207 | 242 | EZ1ET3ZZ ? |       14 |   418951740 |
|          6 | 281 | EIHVH3ZZ ? |       14 |  1182157711 |
|        149 | 287 | X5ZR3LHH ? |       15 |   364819476 |
|         88 | 251 | PT8E2CII ? |       15 |   673475236 |
|        123 | 253 | 8L35PFYY ? |       15 |  1204512525 |
|        190 | 278 | MBW03OUU ? |       16 |   641720378 |
|        160 | 299 | ZT8QRRMM ? |       16 |  1289470813 |
|         75 | 268 | 2G4G42WW ? |       16 |  1427431541 |
|        202 | 297 | H00HLNRR ? |       17 |   374047531 |
|        243 | 204 | O7VUW2NN ? |       17 |   951026810 |
|        300 | 229 | 3XEZG0PP ? |       17 |  1319302198 |
+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
51 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So the questions are **different**.

To get the last results in a shuffled sense:

```
select r.* 
FROM questions_for_user r 
WHERE 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM random r1 WHERE r.category = r1.category AND r.id < r1.id ) <= 2 
ORDER by randomOrder;

+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
| physcOrder | id  | question   | category | randomOrder |
+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
|         64 | 279 | VQN6TVSS ? |        7 |    33942495 |
|        284 | 226 | BQTD6A44 ? |        9 |    45678738 |
|        290 | 277 | DXE1W0GG ? |        7 |   100007602 |
|        291 | 265 | A99UU1YY ? |        8 |   107468716 |
|         56 | 235 | MBPPXJ44 ? |       14 |   109832248 |
|        112 | 286 | ORK15577 ? |        1 |   193281314 |
|         37 | 293 | GFWQ0BEE ? |        2 |   222852606 |
|        232 | 234 | DWZULKBB ? |        5 |   296692881 |
|         32 | 240 | W771N588 ? |       12 |   303493686 |
|        295 | 273 | CC5FGKFF ? |        5 |   337915901 |
|        178 | 290 | O8B4WRCC ? |       11 |   341509950 |
|        149 | 287 | X5ZR3LHH ? |       15 |   364819476 |
|        202 | 297 | H00HLNRR ? |       17 |   374047531 |
|        207 | 242 | EZ1ET3ZZ ? |       14 |   418951740 |
|        193 | 258 | IHK46577 ? |       10 |   460111512 |
|        214 | 298 | QEHHSAEE ? |       10 |   482322673 |
|        176 | 266 | JNQH26DD ? |        1 |   530153269 |
|        212 | 283 | WBQ0DGLL ? |       13 |   595739692 |
|        257 | 271 | TNG23R11 ? |        6 |   619359840 |
|        190 | 278 | MBW03OUU ? |       16 |   641720378 |
|        140 | 252 | Y7V58ZEE ? |        5 |   644987638 |
|         88 | 251 | PT8E2CII ? |       15 |   673475236 |
|        239 | 285 | E3KDJ144 ? |        2 |   679635152 |
|        159 | 300 | 97V6UXYY ? |       13 |   688431139 |
|        179 | 291 | YNT0YN11 ? |        9 |   700305900 |
|        283 | 246 | FTEEVJ00 ? |       12 |   710591266 |
|         31 | 272 | 3YY2EMM ?  |       11 |   726662739 |
|          7 | 263 | SHEVXPBB ? |       10 |   766681927 |
|         28 | 295 | Y85VNBWW ? |        4 |   806083444 |
|         30 | 289 | FUODJHJJ ? |        4 |   814854070 |
|        262 | 275 | U5BFCUFF ? |        2 |   846163956 |
|         27 | 294 | PTEMZ7GG ? |        6 |   869855570 |
|        296 | 267 | T2HPRW88 ? |        1 |   891041924 |
|        177 | 244 | X1JYHUBB ? |       12 |   916685336 |
|        173 | 274 | LQTFS7RR ? |        7 |   946909650 |
|        243 | 204 | O7VUW2NN ? |       17 |   951026810 |
|         52 | 292 | 71JZTMQQ ? |       13 |  1039681379 |
|         49 | 284 | 5PDRR5YY ? |        8 |  1068298164 |
|        228 | 282 | NWZSPCZZ ? |        8 |  1115906220 |
|         34 | 280 | 441X1YTT ? |        4 |  1119188021 |
|          6 | 281 | EIHVH3ZZ ? |       14 |  1182157711 |
|        123 | 253 | 8L35PFYY ? |       15 |  1204512525 |
|         95 | 288 | 6GGOI2CC ? |        3 |  1244253481 |
|        160 | 299 | ZT8QRRMM ? |       16 |  1289470813 |
|        300 | 229 | 3XEZG0PP ? |       17 |  1319302198 |
|         81 | 231 | LQMYMV44 ? |        3 |  1380298624 |
|        297 | 250 | GEH9PVBB ? |       11 |  1386568968 |
|        218 | 276 | 3J1KGJZZ ? |        6 |  1390090875 |
|        164 | 233 | 3IHU1YKK ? |        9 |  1416089612 |
|         59 | 296 | 8MJCWR55 ? |        3 |  1420850554 |
|         75 | 268 | 2G4G42WW ? |       16 |  1427431541 |
+------------+-----+------------+----------+-------------+
51 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The reason the other answers seem to be returning the same questions (top 3 or bottom 3) imo is because of the physical ordering of the table, which is why I created the 2nd table. The second table uses a new bogus physical ordering and the insert into it is via order by random (so the physical order problem doesn't exist). Hope that makes sense.

And of course I poached the answer from pjanaway and couldn't get Gordon's to work on my system though I like his variable approach.

Good luck.