# How can I grab random rows from database based on the key value?

Tags: sql, mysql

For example if I have a 'customers' database similar to:

| state | customer |
| --- | --- |
| Alabama | Adam |
| Alabama | Aaron |
| Oklahoma | Randy |
| California | Sam |
| California | Darren |

And I want to grab 10 random customers from each state, how would I go about accomplishing this?
I could do a union, ie:

```
(SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state = 'Alabama' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state = 'Alaska' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state = 'Arizona' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state = 'Arkansas' LIMIT 10)
...
```

But that seems really inefficient (basically 50 selects).
I could grab the entire database and then parse it after the fact, but that could also get pretty costly. Surely there's a better way?

Comment: You have a customers _table_.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You will need some way to select random records, not just the top 10 from each state. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495446/how-to-get-random-records-from-each-category-in-mysql

Comment: How random do you need this to be? Just some arbitrary 10 records or does it actually need to be statistically random?

Comment: Could possibly use a windows function, maybe something like this... `select * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by state order by random()) as rn from customers) z where rn <= 10` but dialect depends on DBMS. If you truly want random, you need to order by random.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Comment: @jarlh I'm not sure. I'm using phpmyadmin with mysql.

Comment: @Bart McEndree
Just 10 arbitrary.

Comment: To identify exactly the database you're using, run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` This is important because old versions don't support the window functions as suggested by Isolated above.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of variables but under some circumstances a [lateral derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) *may* be faster:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT state FROM customers) AS s
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state = s.state ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
) AS c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` window function without specifying `ORDER BY` to get a somewhat arbitrary result:

```
select customer, state
from (
  select c.*, row_number() over (partition by state) rn
  from customers c
) dt
where rn <= 10
order by state, customer;
```

Demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/M7hHHVyC

Comment: How is this random?

Comment: Random as in _arbitrary rows_.

Answer (score 0):

Number the rows per state in random order, then keep all rows numbered 1 to 10:

```
SELECT state, customer
FROM
(
  SELECT
    state, 
    customer,
    row_number() over(partition by state order by rand()) as rn
  FROM customers 
) c
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY state, customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

To select 10 random customers from each state in the 'customers' table, you can use a combination of window functions and filtering. Here's how you can do it:

```sql
WITH RankedCustomers AS (
    SELECT
        state,
        customer,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY RAND()) AS row_num
    FROM
        customers
)
SELECT state, customer
FROM RankedCustomers
WHERE row_num <= 10;
```

Explanation:

1. The `ROW_NUMBER()` window function assigns a sequential row number to each row within each state partition, ordered randomly (`ORDER BY RAND()`).
2. The `PARTITION BY state` clause ensures that the row numbers reset for each state, so each state's customers are numbered independently.
3. In the outer query, we select only those rows where the row number is less than or equal to 10, effectively selecting 10 random customers from each state.

This query will give you 10 random customers from each state in your 'customers' table. Adjust the table and column names as per your actual schema.